# IIS7 URL Rewrite module rule to unfriendly url

Tags: iis-7, url-rewrite-module

I'm having trouble creating a rewrite rule for the URL rewrite module because I'm attempting to rewrite a url from friendly to querystring.

I have a url like this: 
domain.com/item/1234

i need to redirect this to:
domain.com/item?id=1234

If you're wondering why I need this its because I want to display friendly urls in third party sites and load the page with a querystring so I can change the parameters in the page without a postback using Javascript.

All of the documentation I have found show how to make a url friendly and not the other way around.

Thanks!